# How to prepare a data for decision tree algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have the following aggregated data:

```
Page,UV_NOV, UV_DEC, UV_JAN
---------------------------------------------------
pageA, 10000,9989,11000
pageB, 999,500,700
...
pageZ,200,50,34
```

What I'm trying to do is that using the Nov, Dec and Jan page visits to predict a forecast for the next month (Feb) visits.

However, I'm not sure how I could prepare above data for decision tree regression.

Could you please give me an example or any tools that I could you?